# Analyzing a formula-tree to consolidate formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Excel formulas are often linked with each other.
**Example:**
[image: Demonstration on how formulas could be added together]

As you can see, there is data labelled α-ε.
The final result is some function that is depending on α-ε.

```
f(α,β,γ,δ,ε) = g(α,β,γ,δ,ε) / h(α,β,γ,δ,ε)
```

Now I'd like to see how changing α (or β) *impacts* the final result. To do this, I could use the scenario manager, but I'd like to do a do it with VBA.

The problem is, I don't know the final function! I know that the function is something like `=SUM(.....)/PRODUCT(PRODUCT(SUM(...))..)`, but to produce the output I'd need to have the full function in some VBA-comprehensive form.

To do this, one could see it as a tree. Root being my total, every sub-calculation is a root-child. Every sub-calculation in these childs is yet another child. And by somehow putting all the leafs of the tree together, you could find out the final enormous function.
Does anyone have an idea on how to tackle this problem?

EDIT: Some more info on what I meant:
Say E3 as my output has the function `=SUM(E4;E5)`. 
It is the root of our tree. Now we take a look at all of its components: E4 and E5. Let us do that:
Say E4 as has the function `=PRODUCT(2;2)`.
 Say E5 as has the function `=SQRT(3)`.

My question: How do I get a formula that instead of saying 
`=SUM(E4;E5)`
 it says 
`=SUM(PRODUCT(2;2);SQRT(3))`

Comment: Pro tip: when you are unsure if you should use *affects* or *effects*, use `impacts` ;)

Comment: Are you trying to reverse engineer the function given the output and inputs being known? If not, I don't really understand the question :0

Comment: It's alphabetical: Something that *affects* me has an *effect* on me

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad that is nicely explained ...

Comment: @Maurice - (just to clarify) do you mean you want VBA code to parse the function in `E3` so that when it comes across cells reference (`E4` and `E5` in your (edited) example), it looks at the functions in those cells (if any) and inserts them in the function in `E3` to give what you refer to as the "final" function (let say we put it in `E2`). Would you need such a function to be recursive -- i.e. look at cell references in the functions in `E4` and `E5` and see if those have functions too?

Comment: I think the closest you will get is to step through using Excel's Formula Evaluate tool.

Comment: If you only want to measure changes in one or two variables, you could Data Tables (an, IMO, underused but quite powerful Excel functionality).